# Powershell Loop with two variables

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am looking for a way to pipe many (100 paired variables) items into this powershell script. Each single command has two variables ResourceGroup and AccountName. I can build an array, but not sure how to get the script to execute the paired variables.

EDIT: Would there be any way to import these variables from CSV , or pull them directly.

```
$rgName = "<resource-group>"
$accountName = "<storage-account>"
$location = "<location>"

# Create a storage account with MinimumTlsVersion set to TLS 1.1.
New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgName `
    -AccountName $accountName `
    -Location $location `
    -SkuName Standard_GRS `
    -MinimumTlsVersion TLS1_1

# Read the MinimumTlsVersion property.
(Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $accountName).MinimumTlsVersion

# Update the MinimumTlsVersion version for the storage account to TLS 1.2.
Set-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgName `
    -AccountName $accountName `
    -MinimumTlsVersion TLS1_2

# Read the MinimumTlsVersion property.
(Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $accountName).MinimumTlsVersion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group variables together, you could use an array of [`System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscustomobject?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0), then iterate this array and run your code:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [PSCustomObject[]]
    $StorageAccountData
)

foreach ($obj in $StorageAccountData) {
    $rgName = $obj.ResourceGroupName
    $accountName = $obj.AccountName
    $location = $obj.Location

    # Create a storage account with MinimumTlsVersion set to TLS 1.1.
    New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgName `
        -AccountName $accountName `
        -Location $location `
        -SkuName Standard_GRS `
        -MinimumTlsVersion TLS1_1

    # Read the MinimumTlsVersion property.
    (Get-AzStorageAccount `
        -ResourceGroupName $rgName `
        -Name $accountName).MinimumTlsVersion

    # Update the MinimumTlsVersion version for the storage account to TLS 1.2.
    Set-AzStorageAccount `
        -ResourceGroupName $rgName `
        -AccountName $accountName `
        -MinimumTlsVersion TLS1_2

    # Read the MinimumTlsVersion property.
    (Get-AzStorageAccount `
        -ResourceGroupName $rgName `
        -Name $accountName).MinimumTlsVersion
}
```

Then you could run this script like so:

```
PS C:\Users\user> $storageAccountData = @(
>>     [PSCustomObject]@{
>>         ResourceGroupName = 'storageRG'
>>         AccountName = 'storage1'
>>         Location = 'australiaeast'
>>     }
>>     [PSCustomObject]@{
>>         ResourceGroupName = 'storageRG'
>>         AccountName = 'storage2'
>>         Location = 'australiaeast'
>>     }
>> )
PS C:\Users\user> script.ps1 -StorageAccountData $storageAccountData
```

If you want to *pipe* this into the script, you can create a function and use [`ValueFromPipeline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.1#valuefrompipeline-argument):

```
function MyFunction {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true, 
            ValueFromPipeline = $true
        )]
        [PSCustomObject[]]
        $StorageAccountData
    )
    # rest of your code
}
```

Then pass the array of `PSCustomObject` down then pipeline to this function with `$storageAccountData | MyFunction`. Make sure to [dot source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7.1#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) the script to load the function into your preferred scope before calling the function.

### Update

If you wanted to read from a CSV file(e.g. storage-accounts.csv):

```
AccountName,ResourceGroupName,Location
storage1,storageRG,australiaeast
storage2,storageRG,australiaeast
```

You just need use [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.1):

```
$storageAccountData = Import-Csv -Path .\storage-accounts.csv

foreach ($obj in $storageAccountData) {
    # rest of your code
}
```